# Remove all occurrences of words in a string from a python list

Tags: python, regex

I'm  trying to match and remove all words in a list from a string using a compiled regex but I'm struggling to avoid occurrences within words.

Current:

```
 REMOVE_LIST = ["a", "an", "as", "at", ...]

 remove = '|'.join(REMOVE_LIST)
 regex = re.compile(r'('+remove+')', flags=re.IGNORECASE)
 out = regex.sub("", text)
```

In: *"The quick brown fox jumped over an ant"*

Out: *"quick brown fox jumped over t"*

Expected: *"quick brown fox jumped over"*

I've tried changing the string to compile to the following but to no avail:

```
 regex = re.compile(r'\b('+remove+')\b', flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

Any suggestions or am I missing something garishly obvious?

Comment: Presumably `ant` is part of your remove list?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One problem is that only the first `\b` is inside a raw string. The second gets interpreted as the backspace character (ASCII 8) rather than as a word boundary.

To fix, change

```
regex = re.compile(r'\b('+remove+')\b', flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

to

```
regex = re.compile(r'\b('+remove+r')\b', flags=re.IGNORECASE)
                                 ^ THIS
```

Comment: As a trick to discover this (aside from knowing this beforehand), output the pattern with `regex.pattern`

Comment: A bit cleaner still using f-strings: re.compile(fr"\b({remove})\b")

Answer (score 19):

here is a suggestion without using regex you may want to consider:

```
>>> sentence = 'word1 word2 word3 word1 word2 word4'
>>> remove_list = ['word1', 'word2']
>>> word_list = sentence.split()
>>> ' '.join([i for i in word_list if i not in remove_list])
'word3 word4'
```

Comment: Groovy. Hadn't thought of that. Thanks :)

Comment: It's worth pointing out that this will have difficulty with punctuation, and will not preserve tabs/consecutive whitespaces (not sure if the latter is important).

Comment: It's worth noting that if `remove_list` is large, you would be better off with `remove_set = {'word1', 'word2', ...}` as sets have much faster membership tests.

Comment: @NPE You are right. We don't know the exact usage of the OP so I thought they might want to consider it.