# Exclude list of words when reading a file

Tags: python, regex, list

I am using Python 2.7.4

I have pieced together a program that will read a .txt file, separate the words, remove the whitespace and punctuation, convert capital letters to lowercase, and return the x most common words, along with a count of how many times those words appear in the document.  What I am trying - and have not been able - to do is to exclude certain most common words from the output (i.e., "a", "i", "to", "for", etc.).

I am a beginner, and so I may simply be misunderstanding the responses to certain questions that have already been answered (and that I have not been able to make use of), such as, among others:

[How to remove list of words from a list of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510846/how-to-remove-list-of-words-from-a-list-of-strings/3510974#3510974)

and

[Remove all occurrences of words in a string from a python list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15435726/remove-all-occurrences-of-words-in-a-string-from-a-python-list)

I have tried to separate the different aspects into different functions to hopefully simplify things, though I suspect I may in fact be overcomplicating things.  My program is below:

```
import string

from collections import Counter

def wordlist(line):
    wordlist2 = []
    wordlist1 = line.split()
    for word in wordlist1:
        cleanword = ""
        for char in word:
            if char in string.punctuation:
                char = ""
            if char in string.whitespace:
                char = ""
            cleanword += char
        wordlist2.append(cleanword)
    return wordlist2

def wordcaps(line):
    line = [char.lower() for char in line]
    return line

def countwords(document): 
    words = Counter()
    words.update(document)
    x = words.most_common() 
    print x

def readfile(filename):
    fin = open(filename).read()
    print countwords(wordcaps(wordlist(fin)))
```

Here are some of the things I have tried.  I have tried to create a list - for example, filterlist = ['i', 'to', 'and'] - and to use this as a conditional in the wordlist function:

```
for word in wordlist1:
    if word in filterlist:
        word = ""
```

This does not seem to have any effect.  I have also tried, to no avail:

```
for word in wordlist1:
    if word in filterlist:
        wordlist1.append("")
```

I have tried a bunch of other things, but this question seems to be getting too long in any event.  I have seen references to "regex," but am just not sure what that is or how it fits in.

Comment: This is some pretty good code for a beginner. :) In my experience most beginners would reinvent the wheel rather than using `collections.Counter`. Good job! :)

Comment: Thanks, @kojiro.  This was my first programming compliment :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually is enough to do:

```
for word in wordlist1:
   if word.lower() not in filterlist:
        words.append(word)
```

**words** is the output list containing words which are valid.

Your approach does not work because you're using the same list for storing input and output list `wordlist1`:

```
for word in wordlist1:
    if word in filterlist:
        wordlist1.append("")
```

You could also do something like this:

```
wordlist1 = [word for word in wordslist1 if word not in filterlist]
```

which use an **temporany** list to store the valid words and then assign them back to your original input list.

Comment: Thanks.  Your point that I was using the same list for input and output made this "click" for me.  I have noticed though that while this seems to work almost all the time, certain words such as "me" and "said" do not get filtered out.  Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably simplest to read the input one character at a time and check for the ones to *include* rather than the ones to *exclude*.

Once a candidate word has been extracted, it can then be converted to lower case and tested against a set of words to be skipped.

Here's a possible implementation:

```
def parse(text, skip=()):
    text += '\n'
    words = []
    word = ''
    for char in text:
        if char.isalpha():
            word += char
        elif word:
            word = word.lower()
            if word not in skip:
                words.append(word)
            word = ''
    return words
```

(NB: a newline is appended to the input to make sure the last word gets processed correctly).

Of course, it would be *much* more efficient to do the parsing with a regular expression:

```
import re

def parse(text, skip=()):
    words = []
    for word in re.findall(r'\w+', text):
        word = word.lower()
        if word not in skip:
            words.append(word)
    return words
```

Here's a simple script that uses the parse function to get word counts from an input file:

```
import sys
from collections import Counter

SKIP = set('a an and be i is of so the to'.split())

def main(args):
    try:
        with open(args[0]) as stream:
            words = parse(stream.read(), SKIP)
    except IndexError:
        print 'ERROR: no path given'
    except IOError as exception:
        print 'ERROR: could not read file:'
        print '  :', exception
    else:
        counter = Counter(words)
        print counter.most_common()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    main(sys.argv[1:])
```